# AngularJS 1.x: file upload fails: file object undefined during transfer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am trying to upload a file via rest / json I get a `400` error. I see that my `content` is undefined during the file upload rest request, but it is defined prior to the `reader.readAsArrayBuffer`.

What I'm trying to do is pass a file as a `BASE64` encoded string. I have a feeling I am not doing it correctly in this current context.

Here is the function for uploading.

```
    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        $scope.files.forEach(function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var fileObject = {
                'documentCase': {
                    'id': successResponse.data.documentCase.id,
                    'code': successResponse.data.documentCase.code
                },
                'code': successResponse.data.documentCase.code,
                'content': reader.readAsArrayBuffer(document.getElementById(file.id).files[0]),
                'name':'hi',
                'description':'hi'
            };

            $http.post (webserviceUrl + documentCaseFileCreate, fileObject, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log('file transfer ok');
                console.log(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.error('file transfer error');
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    };
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you read the file ? Are you sure ? Just test the file read function

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız this line of code works 100% `document.getElementById(file.id).files[0]`

Comment: What is the result of `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(document.getElementById(file.id).files[0])` ?

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız `deps.js?bust=7.6.0:40732 Error: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.`

Comment: Try to send just 1 file and read its content totally before send it. Could be `readAsArrayBuffer` op working asynchronized ?

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız I cannot do it, because I get an exception with 400...

Comment: You are sending request before file read finishes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146357/discussion-between-deniss-m-and-burak-akyildiz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move the post call into the function which triggered only after the file has loaded:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(document.getElementById(file.id).files[0]);
    reader.onload = function() {
        var fileObject = {
            'documentCase': {
                'id': successResponse.data.documentCase.id,
                'code': successResponse.data.documentCase.code
            },
            'code': successResponse.data.documentCase.code,
            'content': btoa(reader.result),
            'name':'tere',
            'description':'tere'
        };

        $http.post(webserviceUrl + documentCaseFileCreate, fileObject, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            uploadedFile = {
                'fileData': document.getElementById(file.id).files[0],
                'responseData': response
            };
            console.log('uploadedFile');
            console.log(uploadedFile);
            $scope.uploadedFiles.push(uploadedFile);
            $scope.files.splice(file.);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.error('file transfer error');
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
    reader.onerror = function() {
        console.error('error reading file');
    };

};
```